# Reporting table size to grafana

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I am trying to report partition metric to influxdb so that it can be visualised in grafana. I have partitioned my table using `pg_partman`. I want to report the size of the `default` table that is created by partman. This is the table where rows that don't fall into any of the existing partition tables are inserted into. 
I had 2 approaches in mind

1. `select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('<default table name>'))`
2. `select count(*) from <default table name>`

If I am not wrong 'count(*)' does a full table scan? So it might slow down the query if there are lot of rows being inserted into the default table. 

I am not sure of `pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size ..)` Is that constant time?
Also if there are other ways of doing this I would glad to know about them:)

Answer (score 1):

`pg_total_relation_size` is definitely the way to go. It gets the size of the involved files from the file system, which is fast and not invasive.

If my monitoring system would regularly run `SELECT count(*)` on by big tables, I would kill it. It does a sequential scan and uses lots of resources.

For monitoring, I would not use `pg_size_pretty`. That is good for human readers, but automatic processing will be easier in bytes.